# Dell W3201CHD TV No Response Over HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently built a new computer with a MSi Z97 PC MATE with a EVGA GTX 980Ti Hydro and a Intel i7 4790k @ 4.5 Ghz.  I don't have any HDMI/DVI capable devices at my disposal right now.  I'm currently using the Dell W3201CHD on VGA with a DVI-I to VGA adapter connected to the video card.

I would like to add another monitor.  The other monitor I have only supports VGA, and I know the Dell W3201CHD supports HDMI.  I tried changing it to HDMI through the card, but it doesn't work.  I've checked that HDMI of the monitor and the video card aren't broken, because they work with other devices.

The Dell W3201CHD does run at the unusual resolution of 1360 x 768, which is different from the 1366 x 768 that we're used too.

Is there any way I can fix this so I can be able to use two monitors again?

Comment: Are you using extended mode? Clone and surround need the same resolution.

Comment: No, it registers in window as a separate monitor, but the HDMI doesn't carry the signal or something like that.